# How to add a non-Django python package to a Django project?

Tags: python, django

This is probably one of those annoying newbie questions. I'm trying to use a python package called jieba in my Django project. I've tried pip install and dragging the package folder into my apps directory, but have not succeeded in importing the package (ModuleNotFoundError). Please tell me how this could be done. Thanks!

Edit:
I mean I tried pip install jieba, and it didn't work (ModuleNotFoundError).
I made sure that it was correctly installed in my project virtual environment, but don't know how to import that in the Django project. Tried: `import jieba` and `from jieba import jieba`, no luck.
Then, I tried dragging that folder to the apps directory, and it still didn't work.

Update:
It turns out I have correctly installed jieba, but Atom Runner somehow cannot import it. I switched to PyCharm, and now it works fine. Nothing has changed except the editor.

Comment: Once it is installed by pip all you should need to do is import it. No dragging needed =)

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid  
I mean I tried pip install jieba, and it didn't work. Then, I tried dragging that folder to the apps directory, and it didn't work.

Comment: Download `jieba` from its repo and, with your `venv` activated, cd into the directory with the `setup.py`. Then do `pip install .` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I have correctly installed jieba, but Atom Runner somehow cannot import it. I switched to PyCharm, and now it works fine. Nothing has changed except the editor.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you can't do:

```
import jieba
```

anymore because you've dragged/moved the package folder from where it supposed to be after pip installing it. Try to drag it back or uninstall and install package again, then import as normal.

Also if you are using virtual env make sure you activated your env before installing the package.

Comment: I mean I tried pip install jieba, and it didn't work. Then, I tried dragging that folder to the apps directory, and it didn't work.

Comment: OK, I've just did pip install jieba and then import jieba in my script and it works fine, so it's not about the way you import the package. Try doing pip list | grep jieba to make sure the package has actually been installed and is available in your envoirnment and also make sure you are actually installing packages into the env and work within the env.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I have correctly installed jieba, but Atom Runner somehow cannot import it. I switched to PyCharm, and now it works fine. Nothing has changed except the editor. I like Atom better, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy python package from dist to your project root.
Pip packages is works standalone and not need to implement for django.

this is mean that after you need to only install your package with pip and use in project like following sample :

> pip install jieba

```
# encoding=utf-8
import jieba

seg_list = jieba.cut("我来到北京清华大学", cut_all=True)
print("Full Mode: " + "/ ".join(seg_list))  # 全模式

seg_list = jieba.cut("我来到北京清华大学", cut_all=False)
print("Default Mode: " + "/ ".join(seg_list))  # 精确模式

seg_list = jieba.cut("他来到了网易杭研大厦")  # 默认是精确模式
print(", ".join(seg_list))

seg_list = jieba.cut_for_search("小明硕士毕业于中国科学院计算所，后在日本京都大学深造")  # 搜索引擎模式
print(", ".join(seg_list))
```

Comment: I mean I tried pip install jieba, and it didn't work (ModuleNotFoundError). Then, I tried dragging that folder to the apps directory, and it didn't work. After that, I also tried to add 'jieba' to INSTALLED_APPS list, and no luck. What am I missing here?